# I am having trouble creating a linked list that points to objects in another class

Tags: c++, list

**vlist.h**

```
 class Vlist
    {
    public:
        Vlist();
        ~Vlist();
        void insert(string title, string URL, string comment, float length, int rating);
        bool remove();

    private:
        class Node
        {
        public:
            Node(class Video *Video, Node *next)
            {m_video = Video; m_next = next;}
            Video *m_video;
            Node *m_next;
        };
        Node* m_head;
    };
```

**main.cpp**

```
 int main()
    {
    ....blah blah.... (cin the values)

            Array[i] = new Video(title, URL, comment, length, rating);
            Vlist objVlist;
            objVlist.insert(title, URL, comment, length, rating);
    }
```

vlist.cpp

This is where the error comes from

```
(m_head = new Node(Video, NULL);
```

... the job of this function is to insert a pointer to an object from class video into the list.

```
 void Vlist::insert(string title, string URL, string comment, float length, int rating)
    {
        Node *ptr = m_head;
        //list is empty
        if(m_head == NULL)
            m_head = new Node(Video, NULL);
        else
        {
            ptr = ptr->m_next;
            ptr = new Node(Video, NULL);
        }
        //sort the list every time this executes

    }
```

**video.h**

This is the class i am trying to point to using the linked lists.

```
class Video
{
public:
    Video(string title, string URL, string comment, float length, int rating);
    ~Video();
    void print();
    bool longer(Video *Other);
    bool higher(Video *Other);
    bool alphabet(Video *Other);
private:
    string m_title;
    string m_url;
    string m_comment;
    float m_length;
    int m_rating;
};
```

first time using stack overflow, not too sure what will happen.

Comment: When you write "This is where the error comes from", it's not obvious to anyone what that error is. It would be polite to add a description of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Video" is the name of a class.
You need to create a `Video` instance.

```
void Vlist::insert(string title, string URL, string comment, float length, int rating)
{
    Video* v = new Video(title, URL, comment, length, rating);
    Node *ptr = m_head;
    if(m_head == NULL)
        m_head = new Node(v, NULL);
    else
    {
        ptr = ptr->m_next;
        ptr = new Node(v, NULL);
    }
    // ...
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change

```
m_head = new Node(Video, NULL);
```

to

```
m_head = new Node(new Video(title, URL, comment, length, rating), NULL);
```

and this:

```
else
{
    ptr = ptr->m_next;
    ptr = new Node(Video, NULL);
}
```

is not really the right way to add a new `Node` to the head of the list. Need something like:

```
ptr = new Node(new Video(title, URL, comment, length, rating), NULL);
ptr->m_next = m_head;
m_head = ptr;
```